# Perl: Sorting multi dimensional hash

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, multidimensional-array

I'm currently trying to sort by values in a multi dimensional hash and I'm coming up a bit stumped.

I've done this on a single level as follows:

```
my %exampleHash = ();
$exampleHash{1}{value} = 10;
$exampleHash{2}{value} = 30;
$exampleHash{3}{value} = 0;
$exampleHash{4}{value} = 20;

foreach my $key ( reverse sort {$exampleHash{$a}{value} <=> $exampleHash{$b}{value}} keys %exampleHash )
{
    printf( "%s => %d\n", $key, $exampleHash{$key}{value} );
}
```

This produces the following output, sorted on the value as expected:

```
2 => 30
4 => 20
1 => 10
3 => 0
```

I've then tried the following to do the same thing but with an extra key:

```
my %exampleHashTwo = ();

$exampleHashTwo{1}{"One"}{value} = 10;
$exampleHashTwo{2}{"Two"}{value} = 30;
$exampleHashTwo{3}{"Three"}{value} = 0;
$exampleHashTwo{4}{"Four"}{value} = 20;

foreach my $intKey ( keys %exampleHashTwo )
{
    foreach my $stringKey ( reverse sort {$exampleHashTwo{$intKey}{$a}{value} <=> $exampleHashTwo{$intKey}{$b}{value}} keys %{$exampleHashTwo{$intKey}} )
    {
        printf( "{%d} - {%5s} => %d\n", $intKey, $stringKey, $exampleHashTwo{$intKey}{$stringKey}{value} );
    }
}
```

However this seems to sort the string key's in alphabetical order. So I'm assuming I'm on the right lines, but I've misplaced something perhaps?

```
{4} - { Four} => 20
{1} - {  One} => 10
{3} - {Three} => 0
{2} - {  Two} => 30
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer loop, which loops over the integer keys in somewhat random order, is dictating the order of your output.  The inner loop is sorting but only given one value each time.

To sort all the values for all combinations of both keys, you need a single loop and to sort over a generated list of such combinations:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %exampleHashTwo = ();

$exampleHashTwo{1}{"One"}{value} = 10;
$exampleHashTwo{2}{"Two"}{value} = 20;
$exampleHashTwo{2}{"TwoB"}{value} = 5;
$exampleHashTwo{3}{"Three"}{value} = 0;
$exampleHashTwo{4}{"Two"}{value} = 15;

for my $keypair (
        sort { $exampleHashTwo{$b->[0]}{$b->[1]}{value} <=> $exampleHashTwo{$a->[0]}{$a->[1]}{value} }
        map { my $intKey=$_; map [$intKey, $_], keys %{$exampleHashTwo{$intKey}} } keys %exampleHashTwo
    ) {
    printf( "{%d} - {%5s} => %d\n", $keypair->[0], $keypair->[1], $exampleHashTwo{$keypair->[0]}{$keypair->[1]}{value} );
}
```

Output:

```
{2} - {  Two} => 20
{4} - {  Two} => 15
{1} - {  One} => 10
{2} - { TwoB} => 5
{3} - {Three} => 0
```

(Replaced reverse with switching order of `$a` and `$b`.)

Comment: Some cases could have multiple $intKey and multiple $stringKey yes.

Comment: Thanks, that's done the job. I'll go look into the map function I think. I can't upvote sorry as I don't have 15 rep :(